# Parsing incomming parameters in batch inside for loop with shift

Tags: batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

I am trying to write "bootstrapper" script which parses and passes arguments into further applications in my framework. The minimal, reproducable example below, actual application is much more complicated

The basic syntax for that script is

```
bootstrapper.bat type command "foo=1" "bar=test2" "baz=true"
```

and it should call

```
type/command.bat 1 test2 true
```

The problematic fragment is this nested for-loop:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem this is actually fetched elsewhere in live app
set procedure_arguments_count=3

set arguments=
for /L %%L in (1,1,!procedure_arguments_count!) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ("%~3") do set arguments=!arguments! %%b
    shift /3
)

echo !arguments!
```

The problem is `arguments` are equals to `1 1 1` instead of `1 test2 true` after executing this loop.

I believe the inner loop is pre-populated with `%~3` being set as `foo=1` and ignoring the shift command. I cannot change `shift` as I need to support 9+ arguments, nor can I remove outer loop (for other reasons).

The question is - can I have delayed expansion for script arguments?

Comment: Why not using `set "arguments=%*"` ?

Comment: @jeb I need to discard first two arguments and parse the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem this is actually fetched elsewhere in live app
set procedure_arguments_count=3
set arguments=
for /L %%L in (1,1,!procedure_arguments_count!) do (
    call set "aux=%%~3"
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ("!aux!") do set arguments=!arguments! %%b
    shift /3
)
echo !arguments!
```

or without outer `FOR /L` loop

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "procedure_arguments_count=3"
set "arguments="
set "ii=%procedure_arguments_count%"

:loopfor
  if [%3]==[]   goto :done
  if %ii% EQU 0 goto :done
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ("%~3") do set arguments=%arguments% %%b
  SHIFT /3
  set /A ii-=1
  goto :loopfor
:done

echo(%arguments%
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is, `%x` parameters are replaced by the parser with their initial values even *before* the `for` loop executes, so `shift` has no (immediate) effect inside a `for` loop.

A simple workaround: assign parameters 3....n to a variable and process that:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,*" %%i in ('%*') do (
  for %%k in (%%j) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ("%%~k") do (
      set "args=!args! %%~a"
    )
  )
)
set args
```

The first `for` gets you the parameters 3...
The second `for` processes each of your remaining parameters
The third `for` gets the value from each `var=value` string.